# Workflows Auto Cleanup Timer Job or how to remove Workflow Instances?

Tags: workflow, timer-jobs

I have [read](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662522.aspx), that every now and then the "Workflow Auto Cleanup" job runs and cleans old workflow instances which are older than 60 days are deleted (or something along the lines).

I have a simple Visual Studio workflow attached to a list and it is running on let's say 5 items.

When I delete 4 of these items, the Workflow Status page of the list `WrkSetng.aspx` still displays 5 instances of my workflow, even though I deleted 4 list items (via the normal UI - no code involved). I atually have never bothered about the number of workflow instaces, but I have several thousand workflow instances running, so if the old ones don't get deleted automatically I might run into a problem.

So my question is: Do I have to delete each workflow instance (including workflow history etc.) manually from the list item, e.g. by using `spSite.WorkflowManager.RemoveWorkflowFromListItem(myWorkflow)` or do I just have to wait the 60 days and Sharepoint takes care of the rest?

I even tried running the "Workflow Auto Cleanup" job from the Central administration via *Run Now*, but it didn't seem to do anything - the number of workflow instances as reported by the settings page stayed at 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, you just have to wait the 60 days. According to the article you linked to on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662504.aspx):

> By default, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 runs a daily Workflow Auto Cleanup job to permanently delete workflow instances and related task entries that still exist 60 days after a workflow is completed or canceled. Workflow history items themselves are not deleted, but the entry point to view them on the status page for a particular instance of a workflow will no longer be available.

(Note this is the same for WSS 3.0 / SP 2007).

If you want more control over this, set the [AutoCleanupDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowassociation.autocleanupdays.aspx) property on the SPWorkflowAssociation class (here's an [example](http://snahta.blogspot.com/2009/01/workflow-auto-cleanup-days-fix.html)).

Finally, if you want to delete the workflow history items themselves, check out the [Cleanup Workflow History](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CleanWorkflowHistory) tool provided by an MS partner.

I'm not sure how much of an issue it really is having thousands of history items lying around - provided there's not many queries being run on them during business hours. Perhaps running that many workflows at once will cause you more of an issue first!